# FQL event_member query returns nothing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to select if a specific user (ie. the user logged in) is attending at a specific event. Because I don't want to use Graph API for getting always all the events a user is attending, I tried FQL `SELECT rsvp_status from event_member where eid = {0} and uid = {1}`, but it returned nothing. But when I tried this information getting from Graph API, I succeeded. 
One thing came to my mind, maybe I gave access_token in a wrong way to the FB.Data.query function, because I only saw examples in blogs and articles, not on FB documentation.

Any help appreciated,

Tamas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. As I tested, FB.Data.query.wait is an asynchronous call, that means when FB gives back the results, it waits the main rendering to finish and then runs the callback, so it seems that it hasn't run, because the variables I set in there are set after the page is rendered.
Now I have to find a way to asynchronously write back in the rendered page.